# How to monitor / sniff localhost SVN protocol messages

Tags: svn, monitoring, sniffing

We have a local SVN client and server on localhost
I would like to "sniff" all SVN protocol messages sent to the SVN server
How can that be done?

Comment: What platform is this on?

Answer (score 2):

Most tools won't show local (internal to the one computer) network traffic.  You need a tool that can get deep into the local IP stack.

Try Sysinternal's TCPView http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437

Answer (score 2):

You will need a tool which can sniff loopback or raw sockets. Try using [RawCap](http://www.netresec.com/?page=RawCap).