# How can I monitor ports on Windows?

Tags: windows-8, port, port-forwarding, nmap, fiddler

What is the simplest way on "local" (1*) Windows, for known ports, to:

1. Find out if it is used.
2. Find out as much as possible about what is behind the port.
3. Find out as much as possible about traffic through the port.
4. Find out if something else is interfering with the port and traffic to it.
5. Find new apps coming up (Like the firewall)

I have used Fiddler in the past, but I think that's mostly HTTP?  I don't if Wire-shark does more?  I think there is a tool closely integrated with Windows?  Which one? (5b).
I am looking at NMap, but its seems to be more a suite of tools, and a high entry level.

1*:
Primarily this is for what happens inside my Windows Machine, but if necessary, I can for example use a VM, or the wireless connection.

Answer (score 0):

Wire shark will show you everything there is to know from yourside of the port.  If wireshark doesn't show it I't probably can't be found.

YOu'll probably find with 2 and 4 you can't find any information.

Comment: I am trying it now :-)
How to do the first step is not so intuitive, but I see a lot of what is going on on my machine :-)

Comment: So far, TcpView seems easier for local work:
http://superuser.com/questions/247669/how-to-monitor-sniff-localhost-svn-protocol-messages